# Logging predict request/response in tensorflow serving

Tags: docker, tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-serving, mlops

Currently using TensorFlow serving via docker to deploy an object detection model. Is there a way to log all predict requests/responses so I can save and view them locally for debugging? Input image coming in as a binary string. Is it possible with docker or is there another way that involves changing source code and building a custom image? Is there another deployment tool that would do this better?